# Get specialized row counts

Tags: crystal-reports

I am generating reports using crystal reports.

My report filters data based on two possible values, *Arcade* or *Franchise*. The records can include both values. I want to get two totals for these values such that records with both values count towards both.

I filter data as Arcade = 1 , Franchise = 2 and Both = 0.

How can i get two totals for these values?

Comment: can you share the snapshot of your report.

Comment: Write a formula, search docs about crystal syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create two Running Totals in your footer.

For the Arcade total, count any record that has a filter value of 1 or 0.
For Franchise, count any record with 2 or 0.

Comment: I am new to crystal reports. can you help me with the formula?